# How do I get a token needed for DFS Kerberos authentication?

Tags: kerberos, documentum, documentum-dfs

I'm trying to write a client for consuming DFS (Documentum Foundation Services) and trying to use Kerberos for single sign-on.  Both Java and C# sample code (productivity layer) in the documentation gives the following line which gets the Kerberos binary token:

> byte[] ticket = ...

I'm not sure how to *actually get the binary token*, and the "..." doesn't help me. Does anyone know how to get an actual ticket (Kerberos token) using either Java or C#?

Here are the examples given for both Java and C#:

**Java: Invoking a service with Kerberos authentication**

```java
KerberosTokenHandler handler = new KerberosTokenHandler();
IObjectService service = ServiceFactory
.getInstance().getRemoteService(..., contextRoot, Arrays.asList((Handler) handler));
byte[] ticket = ...;
handler.setBinarySecurityToken(
new KerberosBinarySecurityToken(ticket, KerberosValueType.KERBEROSV5_AP_REQ));
service.create(...)
```

**C#: Invoking a service with Kerberos authentication**

```cs
KerberosTokenHandler handler = new KerberosTokenHandler();
List<IEndpointBehavior> handlers = new List<IEndpointBehavior>();
handlers.Add(handler);
IObjectService service = ServiceFactory
.Instance.GetRemoteService<IObjectService>(..., contextRoot, handlers);
byte[] ticket = ...;
handler.SetBinarySecurityToken(
new KerberosBinarySecurityToken(ticket, KerberosValueType.GSS_KERBEROSV5_AP_REQ));
service.create(...);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured this out for .NET and would like to share for those who maybe interested.  What's needed is WSE3 library.  Make sure to configure your DFS service account for Kerberos delegation.

So what need to do is set your KerberosTokenHandler with the Kerberos token.  The KerberosBinarySecurityToken comes from WSE3.  The code would look something like this:

```
KerberosTokenHandler kerberosTokenHandler = new KerberosTokenHandler();

String servicePrincipalName = “DFS/example66”;  // this is the service principal name for your DFS service account in Active Directory.
using (KerberosClientContext kerberosClientContext = new KerberosClientContext(servicePrincipalName, true, ImpersonationLevel.Delegation))
{
      KerberosBinarySecurityToken token = new KerberosBinarySecurityToken(kerberosClientContext.InitializeContext(), KerberosValueType.KERBEROSV5_AP_REQ);
      kerberosTokenHandlerandler.SetBinarySecurityToken(token);
}
```